# url scheme to open evernote in Android

Tags: evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I need to open the Evernote app installed on an Android smartphone from a web application. I already can do that on iOS by using the url scheme "evernote://" that opens the app automatically.

Does anyone know any Android alternative for that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for information about [note links](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php). Also note that http note links forward to the app (via an evernote:// note link) if the app is installed.